# Can I create an OSX System Preferences pane with Qt

Tags: macos, qt, nspreferencepane

I am creating an application in Qt to modify settings for a USB audio device. I need these setting to appear in System Preferences in OSX.

According to the apple documentation ([Preference Pane Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Concepts/Anatomy.html)) the NSPrincipalClass entry in the bundle Info.plist would need to specify a Qt binary that subclasses NSPreferencePane rather than NSApplication. I have looked through the Qt documentation and searched the forums and see no reference on how to do this. I was ready to give up when I ran across [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397177/platform-native-preferences-dialog-with-qt-on-mac-gnome-kde-and-windows/5716861#5716861) which eludes to it being possible to create OSX preference panes from Qt, but unfortunately gives no clues as to how this might have been achieved.

Is it possible to create an OSX System Preferences panel using Qt? Any help or advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.